# I can not render a group of box inside a dashboardbody using shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I can't render the box in the dashboardbody.

It shows the whole panel but with anything on them.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(qcc)


  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 350,

      sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Falcon 1",tabName = "Falcon 11")
      ,
      menuItem("Falcon 2",tabName = "Falcon 22")))

   body<- dashboardBody(
          tabItems(
              tabItem(tabName="Falcon 11",
        box(plotOutput("histogram")),
        box(plotOutput("chart2")),
        box(plotOutput("chart3")),
        box(plotOutput("chart4"))),
          tabItem(tabName="Falcon 22",
        box(plotOutput("chart5")),
        box(plotOutput("chart6")),
        box(plotOutput("chart7")),
        box(plotOutput("chart8")),
        box(plotOutput("chart9")),
        box(plotOutput("chart10")))))


   ui <- dashboardPage(
     dashboardHeader(title = "Control Charts - Horno Glasston", titleWidth = 350),sidebar,body)
```

When I am rendering the app, it only shows me the panel but not all the box inside each tabItem.

I have just started with R and I am struggling a lot with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you use blank in your `tabName`, just change `Falcon 11` to `Falcon_11` (`Falcon 22` also) and it should work fine, I think this a kind of bug of `shiny`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(qcc)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 350,

                            sidebarMenu(
                              menuItem("Falcon 1",tabName = "Falcon_11")
                              ,
                              menuItem("Falcon 2",tabName = "Falcon_22")))

body<- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="Falcon_11",
            box(plotOutput("histogram")),
            box(plotOutput("chart2")),
            box(plotOutput("chart3")),
            box(plotOutput("chart4"))),
    tabItem(tabName="Falcon_22",
            box(plotOutput("chart5")),
            box(plotOutput("chart6")),
            box(plotOutput("chart7")),
            box(plotOutput("chart8")),
            box(plotOutput("chart9")),
            box(plotOutput("chart10")))))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Control Charts - Horno Glasston", titleWidth = 350),sidebar,body)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$histogram<-renderPlot({
    # plot(1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I have changed and it is still the same.

Comment: Sorry my fault, see the revised answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new with R so i did not know about that issue. Do you know if i can create a .exe from this code? Thank you for your time.

Comment: R and shiny app is not possible to compile into exe file, you can set up a shiny-server or deploy on https://www.shinyapps.io